# Does setting the timeout on the net.Dialer and deadline on the Connection result to the same behaviour?

Tags: go, connection, timeout

In Go I create the Connection (with a timeout) from the Dialer:

```
d := net.Dialer{Timeout: timeout, LocalAddr: *localAddr}
c.conn, err = d.Dial("tcp", address)
```

However, then I can also set the deadline for the Connection:

```
 c.conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeout));
```

Is this redundant, or setting the timeout and the deadline here have functional differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are completely different.

The [net.Dialer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer) is used to establish connections. **The deadline (or timeout) applies to connection establishment**. Quoting the docs for the `Timeout` and `Deadline` fields respectively:

> Timeout is the maximum amount of time a dial will wait for a
> connect to complete.
>
> Deadline is the absolute point in time after which dials will
> fail.

On the other hand, a [net.Conn](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) holds an established connection. **The timeout applies to read/write operations on the connection**. This is also clearly stated in the docs for `net.Conn`:

> SetDeadline sets the read and write deadlines associated with the
> connection. It is equivalent to calling both SetReadDeadline and
> SetWriteDeadline.

Note that this is a common set of timeouts (among others): one for connection establishment, another for operations on an established connection.

Comment: But that would mean that every single time I do the read/write operations on the connection I must recalculate as manually reset the deadline.   That does not seem sane. There should be a way to set a timeout for the connection once, should't it?

Comment: That's just how it works. Feel free to file an issue against the go devs.

Comment: @DraifKroneg check out this [blog](https://medium.com/@zombiezen/canceling-i-o-in-go-capn-proto-5ae8c09c5b29) where it shows how to tie a cancelable context to an `io.Reader`. Wrapping a `net.Conn` with this logic frees your app logic from having to manage external cancellation events.